# Nice slider with an old jQuery version

Tags: jquery, slider

I have an old jQuery version (1.2.6). 
I can't upgrade it.
The problem is that I want to use a nice slider with small bullets for navigation and fade in/out effects.

I found that slider : [nova slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/features/).
I tested it with the latest jQuery (1.7) and it works great. But on the 1.2.6 version, I got the following error message : `o is not a function` coming from the slider library.

Is there an alternative for older jQuery versions ?

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [nivo slider github](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider). The issue is that it uses [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in three places, which is jQuery 1.3+. However all three appear beneath the only code that creates matching elements, e.g.

```
slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">' ...
:
$('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
```

which means there's no actual reason to use `.live` (which matches all current and future elements) as opposed to `.bind` (which matches all current elements). Simply replace the three instances of `.live` with `.bind`:

```
$('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).bind('click', function(){
```

and nivo slider will work fine with 1.2.6. You should be able to edit this in the packed version of the script too.